# Python : ValueError: could not convert string to float in real time data

Tags: python, string, pyqt, type-conversion, string-parsing

I want to build an ecg. the filter is built in udoo, then I want to plot the signal in python. however it keeps getting this while I run my code:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float.

```
 import serial
 import sys
 import time
 from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
 import numpy as np
 import pyqtgraph as pg


 # constants
 BAUDE_RATE = 9600
 ARDUINO_MAX_INT = 2 ** 10
 ARDUINO_MAX_VOLTAGE = 3.3
 WINDOW_SIZE = 30
 MAX_DATA_SIZE = 1024

 # declare the Window
 app = QtGui.QApplication([])
 win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Arduino Analog Plotter")
 win.resize(1000, 600)

 # initialize plots 
 raw_plot = win.addPlot(title="Raw Pin Data")
 raw_curve = raw_plot.plot(pen='y')
 raw_plot.addLegend()
 raw_plot.showGrid(True, True)
 raw_plot.setYRange(0, 1200)
 raw_plot.setXRange(0, 1024)

 # disable auto size of the x-y axis
 raw_plot.enableAutoRange('xy', False)
 raw_data = np.zeros(1024)
 # open serial
 ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 115200, timeout=1)
 line = pg.InfiniteLine(pos=1024, angle=0, pen=(24, 215, 248))
 raw_plot.addItem(line)

 ser.flushInput()
 def gettemp(ser):
     ser.write('t')
     ser.flush()
     return ser.readline().strip('\r').strip('\n').split(' ').pop(7)

 def update():
     global raw_data
     # open serial port
     raw_capture = []
     for x in range(WINDOW_SIZE):
         sensoroutput=gettemp()

         r=sensoroutput
         ser.readline().strip('\r').strip('\n').split(' ').pop(7)
         raw_capture.append(float(r).pop(7))

     raw_data = np.concatenate([raw_data, raw_capture])

     # remove first bin to make room for new bin

     if len(raw_data) > MAX_DATA_SIZE:
         raw_data = raw_data[WINDOW_SIZE:]

     # plot data
     raw_curve.setData(raw_data)


 def savecounter():
     ser.close()


 import atexit

 atexit.register(savecounter)
 timer = QtCore.QTimer()
 timer.timeout.connect(update)
 timer.start(0)
 ## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
     import sys

if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: Please post the exact stack trace/error you're getting.  That stack trace will tell you the line of code which encounters the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your sensoroutput seems to be a string.
You cannot convert it directly with `float()` :

```
raw_capture.append(float(r).pop(7))
```

Can you post what is the output of sensoroutput?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just taking a wild stab here, but usually if you have both `\r` and `\n` for line endings the `\r` comes first and the `\n` comes second. The way you're stripping off those characters, the `\r` will remain because you try to `strip` it first, before the `\n` has been removed; `float()` will fail on the non-numeric character in the string.  Try this instead, it will remove both end-of-line characters at the same time:

```
ser.readline().strip('\r\n').split(' ').pop(7)
```

Comment: it getting different error. it become like this :                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_serial.py", line 48, in update
    sensoroutput=gettemp()
TypeError: gettemp() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)s :

Comment: @AhmadNurianto just because I've pointed out one problem with your program doesn't mean there aren't others...